# Getting an element from vector<object*> *object

Tags: c++, stl

I have a grid of objects (x,y) and I inserted them into one linear vector.

```
struct Invaders_t
{
    vector<Invader*> *invaders;
}

struct Invaders_t g_Invaders; 

    int y_spacing = 50;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        x_spacing = 15;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Invader *invader = new Invader();
            g_Invaders.invaders->push_back(invader);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to an invader out of that, I know the equation will be like
`x + y*sizeOfVector;` but I don't know the syntax to get an invader out of that pointer to pointer of invaders.

Further more, How would I remove an element from vector ?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. When you construct the `g_Invaders` struct, you don't initialize the vector pointer and thus its just a junk pointer.

Comment: Presumably he just did not show the code that initializes `g_Invaders` before using it.

Comment: Get rid of all those pointers and use ordinary objects instead.  This will make half of your problems go away immediately.  For the second half, read the documentation of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  It has a wealth of useful operations defined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I wouldn't assume that.  The fact that we have pointers to vectors of pointers suggests some problems in conception and design from the outset.

Comment: Or, maybe a `vector` exists elsewhere in memory that `Invader_t` will be pointing at, and that assignment code was simple not shown here.  Let's not make assumptions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I would like to an invader out of that, I know the equation will be like `x + y*sizeOfVector;` but I don't know the syntax to get an invader out of that pointer to pointer of invaders.

It would be like this:

```
Invader *pinvader = (*(g_Invaders.invaders))[(x*NumberOfItemsInARow)+y];
```

Or:

```
Invader *pinvader = g_Invaders.invaders->at((x*NumberOfItemsInARow)+y);
```

Do note that the `[]` operator does not perform bounds checking, whereas the `at()` method does.

> Further more, How would I remove an element from vector ?

Like this:

```
std::vector<Invader*>::iterator iter = g_Invaders.invaders->begin();
std::advance(iter, (x*NumberOfItemsInARow)+y);
Invader *invader = *iter;
g_Invaders.invaders->erase(iter);
delete invader;
```

Comment: "Do note that the `[]` operator performs bounds checking, whereas the `at()` method does not." – that's the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

**You can access elements of a vector using the `[]` operator:**

```
for ( int i = 0; i < invaders.size(); i++ ) {
    invaders[i]->doSomething();
}
```

**Or if you're using C++11, you can use a range-based for-loop:**

```
for ( auto& i : invaders ) {
    i->doSomething();
}
```

On a side note, you likely want `Invaders_t` to hold a vector instead of a pointer to a vector, and you don't need it to hold pointers to `Invader` objects unless you're using polymorphism (in which case, you should be using smart pointers anyway):

`std::vector<Invader> invaders;`

**For (x, y) indexing, you could use something like this:**

```
Invader& at( size_t x, size_t y ) {
    return invaders.at( x + y * row_size );
}
```

**As for removing:**

```
auto end = std::remove_if( invaders.begin(), invaders.end(),
    []( const Invader& i ) { return i.isDead(); } );
invaders.erase( end, invaders.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

a) First `g_Invaders.invaders` should be allocated a memory or point to already created `std::vector` of `Invader*`

b) Second to iterate over vector you can do following :

```
  typedef vector<Invader*>::iterator It;
  for (It i = g_Invaders.invaders->begin(); i != g_Invaders.invaders->end(); ++i )
  {
     Invader *curr_invader = *i ;
     // use curr_invader as needed
  }
```

c) To delete use :

```
It i = g_Invaders.invaders->begin();
It j = i + ( x* NumberOfItemsInARow )+y; // advance iterator i 
delete *j;
g_Invaders.invaders->erase(j);
```

Comment: You can use `std::advance()` (or `std::next()` in C++11) instead of `j = i + ...`, and also you are calling `delete j` when you should be calling `delete *j` instead (and need to do so before removing the iterator).

Comment: there is no remove(j)

Comment: @andreahmed sorry confusing `remove` from algorithm header